# Static variable used in project android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How do i find where static variable are used in android studio project? Is there any way to find such variables . As my project is too big and i want to remove possible memory leaks. Help me to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: ctrl+shift+f let you search in whole project, I know this is not good solution

Comment: Thanks for your help. but i need list of all the static variable used in project

Comment: Do a search for `static`, then

Comment: I think the best way is that you should create a folder such as utils and add a java class, and make that class to store and fetch all your static variables. I hope you have understand it., then searching will be pretty much easier. I have implemented it.

Comment: @RahulKhurana, I have posted an answer in response to your question. This will definitely work since I use it as well... :) . There is not exact way except the brute force. But you can refine the brute force a lot by specifying filters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using this trick for a very long time now. I am sure this will definitely help you. Follow the instructions step by step and this will help...

[image: Project Search]

1. If you are using windows, Press Ctrl + Shift + F to open entire project search...
2. Next, In the text to find add this **Regex** (public|private|protected) static and under options select case sensitive and Regular expression. This will match public static or private static or protected static.
3. In the scope, select the **project production files**
4. Set the **file mask as *.java**
5. Set the context as **except comments and string literals**

When you hit Find, you will get 1000's of results. You will find results like this:

[image: Search results]

**Completely ignore the usages in generated code.... IMPORTANT**

**Only search in the found occurences for your static variables.**

PS :

1. One drawback with this is that this will match static methods too... such as *public static int randomMethod() { }*
2. If your static variables don't have access specifiers such as public private or protected, just use **regex as static** .

Comment: No probs... Good luck

Answer (score 1):

1.Open your andorid project.

2.Click **ctrl+shift+f**

You will get a dialog box.

Then search **static**

You will get all static members and functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do right-click on said variable and choose `Find Usages`:

[image]

Result will be revealed on `Find` panel on bottom-right of the window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. but i need list of all the static variable used in project

Comment: Ow sorry, did't get that part. I see that you've found the solution above.